# How do I filter a Map in Dart so that all values are unique?

Tags: dart

I have a list that's formatted like `{0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c", 3: "a"}` and want to remove dublicate values so that I end up with `{0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"}`. I'm also fine with geting `{1:"b", 2:"c", 3: "a"}`. What's the most idiomatic way to do this filtering?

Comment: With your reputation you should know questions like "How do I do X" with no additional effort do not follow SO guidelines.

Comment: @im_baby : It would make sense to read the guidelines yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask says nothing against this kind of question. I think there's a good chance that this question is more valuable then the average question on SO because people who google the question in the future will find it. This question is completely in the spirit in which SO is founded. The quality of a question isn't about whether you engaged in Puritian effort. Earning reputation with questions is about asking valuable question and this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change an existing map, you can do the following. I have made it as a extension method but you can of course also just have it as a separate method or some lines of codes:

```
extension RemoveDuplicateValuesExtension<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  void removeDuplicateValues() {
    final valuesSoFar = <V>{};
    this.removeWhere((_, value) => !valuesSoFar.add(value));
  }
}

void main() {
  final map = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "a"}..removeDuplicateValues();
  print(map); // Prints: {0: a, 1: b, 2: c}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) provides a bidirectional map ([`BiMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/BiMap-class.html)) that makes it an error to add elements that don't have unique values.

Alternatively, one easy way to filter duplicate values is to create a separate `Set` of values and use it to rebuild the `Map`:

```dart
Map<K, V> removeDuplicateValues<K, V>(Map<K, V> map) {
  var valuesSoFar = <V>{};
  return {
    for (var mapEntry in map.entries)
      if (valuesSoFar.add(mapEntry.value)) mapEntry.key: mapEntry.value,
  };
}

void main() {
  var map = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "a"};
  print(removeDuplicateValues(map)); // Prints: {0: a, 1: b, 2: c}
}
```

Comment: And if you want to modify your existing `Map` you can use `removeWhere` also with the `Set`: `final valuesSoFar = <V>{}; map.removeWhere((_, value) => !valuesSoFar.add(value));`

Comment: @julemand101 can you add this as an answer?